# Rotating an SVG image using D3.JS not working

Tags: d3.js, svg-animate

I've been trying to rotate some gears in an svg image clockwise repeatedly using D3.js but I can't seem to understand what's wrong with the code or the image. I was able to translate and rotate each gear  using this code below...

```
d3.selectAll(".st6")
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d, i, n) { return i * 50; })
  .on("start", function repeat() {
      d3.active(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(2500)
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(0)')
        .transition() //And rotate back again
        .duration(2500)
        .attr('transform' , 'rotate(90) ')
        .on("start", repeat); //at end, call it again to create infinite loop
  });
```

But when I tried using the same code that did rotate a text repeatedly for me, the image became static and not moving again...

here is the code that rotate a text repeatedly for me...

```
var width = 600;
var height = 300;
    
var holder = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)    
.attr("height", height); 
    
//draw the text
holder.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("font-size", "56px")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0)")
  .text("Hi, how r u doing");
    
var i = 0;
var timeInterval = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    i += 1;
    update(i % 360) 
}, timeInterval);
    
var n;
// update the element
function update(n) {
    // rotate the text
    holder.select("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}
```

Here is what I tried replicating the above method but to no avail...

```
var width = 600;
var height = 300;
    
var holder = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)    
  .attr("height", height); 
    
holder.append("svg:image")
  .attr("image-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("xlink:href", "produc.svg")
  .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate(0)")
// Initial starting angle of the text
    
var i = 0;
var timeInterval = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    i += 1;
    update(i % 360) 
},timeInterval);
    
    
var n;
// update the element
function update(n) {
    // rotate the text
    holder.select("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}
```

Here is a working example on CodePen[click here](https://codepen.io/pellumie/pen/LYREwZo)

Comment: In your update function you haven't updated this line `holder.select("text")` - are you trying to rotate a text element or an image?

Comment: I'm trying to rotate the image but I'm not really sure what is the correct thing to put there.

Comment: Please turn your code into a runnable [mre], so we can debug it and provide you with better answers. You can use runnable stack snippets, or an external jsFiddle/Codepen.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that rightaway.

Comment: Kindly check the question for the codepen link

Comment: I think you're using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.  You could probably get away with simple CSS. [Take a look at this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138801/rotate-rectangle-around-its-own-center-in-svg).

Comment: My problem is rotating the gears continously

Comment: Then, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309085/how-to-specify-the-x-y-rotation-point-when-using-animatetransform). I'm sure that a quick search would help you, here, or you could try referring to the [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element). D3.js, though, is overkill.

Comment: ...especially as you've entered most of the code you're going to use in the attributes!

Answer (score 1):

As for the problem with your code (without considering if it is "a sledgehammer to crack a nut"):

You're taking working code that rotates text and not fully updating it to reflect that you are now working with an image. You have updated the append statement to append an image, but you haven't updated the `update` function to select that image - it's still looking for a text element:

```
function update(n) {
    // rotate the text
    holder.select("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}
```

Since there is no longer a text element, this function doesn't select anything and consequently, doesn't set any element's transform. AS noted in the comment you need to select the image:

```
function update(n) {
    // rotate the text
    holder.select("image")
      .attr("transform", "translate(300,150) rotate("+n+")");
}
```

As seen below:

```js
var width = 600;
var height = 300;
    
var holder = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)    
  .attr("height", height); 
    
holder.append("svg:image")
  .attr("image-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/compass.svg")
  .attr("transform", "translate(200,20) rotate(0)")
  .attr("width", 100)
// Initial starting angle of the text
    
var i = 0;
var timeInterval = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    i += 1;
    update(i % 360) 
},timeInterval);
    
// update the element
function update(n) {
    // rotate the text
    holder.select("image")
      .attr("transform", "translate(200,20) rotate("+n+",50,50)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works by rotating the image but still doesn't rotate it at a fixed point. I want the image to stay fixed at a point while the gears/teeth rotate as if you're spinning a bicycle tyre at a spot

Comment: @DevLayi, You can rotate around a point, specified as the second and third parameters of `rotate()` the image I used has a width/height of 100pixels, so `rotate(degrees,50,50)` will work here. Added that to the answer snippet.